Normalise across multi-dimensional array
I have large multi-dimensional array data that at its most basic looks something like this:
[
  {
    'a': 'a1',
    'b': [
           {
             'ba': 'ba1',
             'bb': 1,
             'bc': {
                     'bca': 'bca1',
                     'bcb': 4
                   }
           },
           {
             'ba': 'ba2',
             'bb': 2,
             'bc': {
                     'bca': 'bca2',
                     'bcb': 5
                   }
           },
           {
             'ba': 'ba3',
             'bb': 3,
             'bc': {
                     'bca': 'bca3',
                     'bcb': 6
                   }
           }
         ]
  },
  ...
]

and what I want to do is to normalise the "bb" and "bcb" values within each object in the top-level array.
That is, I want to end up with this:
[
  {
    'a': 'a1',
    'b': [
           {
             'ba': 'ba1',
             'bb': 0,
             'bc': {
                     'bca': 'bca1',
                     'bcb': 0
                   }
           },
           {
             'ba': 'ba2',
             'bb': 0.5,
             'bc': {
                     'bca': 'bca2',
                     'bcb': 0.5
                   }
           },
           {
             'ba': 'ba3',
             'bb': 1,
             'bc': {
                     'bca': 'bca3',
                     'bcb': 1
                   }
           }
         ]
  },
  ...
]

Is there a package or similar I can do this with in python?
Obviously I can do this with a complicated loop, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

To be clear, what you have is not an array.

You can define a function to do this:
The function below extracts the values from the dictionaries, normalizes the values and replace the original values. The second function (printing in a nice fashion is not needed, it's just cosmetics):
import numpy as np
import json

def normalize_data(data):
    for obj in data:
        bb_values = [item['bb'] for item in obj['b']]
        bcb_values = [item['bc']['bcb'] for item in obj['b']]

        bb_min, bb_max = min(bb_values), max(bb_values)
        bcb_min, bcb_max = min(bcb_values), max(bcb_values)

        normalized_bb = [(bb - bb_min) / (bb_max - bb_min) if bb_max > bb_min else 0 for bb in bb_values]
        normalized_bcb = [(bcb - bcb_min) / (bcb_max - bcb_min) if bcb_max > bcb_min else 0 for bcb in bcb_values]

        for i, item in enumerate(obj['b']):
            item['bb'] = normalized_bb[i]
            item['bc']['bcb'] = normalized_bcb[i]

    return data

data = [
  {
    'a': 'a1',
    'b': [
           {'ba': 'ba1', 'bb': 1, 'bc': {'bca': 'bca1', 'bcb': 4}},
           {'ba': 'ba2', 'bb': 2, 'bc': {'bca': 'bca2', 'bcb': 5}},
           {'ba': 'ba3', 'bb': 3, 'bc': {'bca': 'bca3', 'bcb': 6}}
         ]
  }
]

normalized_data = normalize_data(data)

def print_nicely_formatted_output(data):
    formatted_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    print(formatted_data)

print_nicely_formatted_output(normalized_data)

Which gives you
[
    {
        "a": "a1",
        "b": [
            {
                "ba": "ba1",
                "bb": 0.0,
                "bc": {
                    "bca": "bca1",
                    "bcb": 0.0
                }
            },
            {
                "ba": "ba2",
                "bb": 0.5,
                "bc": {
                    "bca": "bca2",
                    "bcb": 0.5
                }
            },
            {
                "ba": "ba3",
                "bb": 1.0,
                "bc": {
                    "bca": "bca3",
                    "bcb": 1.0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

